Optimize Neo4j allShortestPaths for large datasets
I got the following object in neo4j which describes a policy document (in this case the OWASP Testing Guide)
{
"identity": 854,
  "labels": [
    "NeoDocument",
    "NeoStandard",
    "NeoNode"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "doctype": "Standard",
    "subsection": "",
    "section_id": "",
    "name": "OWASP Web Security Testing Guide (WSTG)",
    "description": "",
    "section": "WSTG-CRYP-04",
    "document_id": "49daea6c-7087-4827-9677-151f7afbcd78",
    "version": "",
    "tags": [
      ""
    ]
  },
  "elementId": "4:c878d015-bb6a-42f7-af47-62aee3951057:854"
}

and all "NeoStandard" docs are connected only to "NeoCRE" docs which carry the same kind of information (but have a different label).
In neo4j for every entry of NeoStandard with name "A" I want to find a shortest path between this entry and every entry of NeoStandard named "B" if they're connected at all.
My query looks like the following
PROFILE
            OPTIONAL MATCH (BaseStandard:NeoStandard {name: "A"})
            OPTIONAL MATCH (CompareStandard:NeoStandard {name: "B"})
            OPTIONAL MATCH p = allShortestPaths((BaseStandard)-[*..20]-(CompareStandard))
            WITH p
            WHERE ALL(n in NODES(p) WHERE (n:NeoCRE or n = BaseStandard or n = CompareStandard)) 
            RETURN p

problem is that this query is incredibly costly and takes several hours if either A or B have more than a few 10s of nodes.
How can I optimize this specific query to make it return faster? All I'm trying to do is find the length of the shortest path between two nodes, it has no reason being this slow.
Other things i tried:
indexes on the "name" parameter, using the apoc library with
MATCH (BaseStandard:NeoStandard {name: "A"})
MATCH (CompareStandard:NeoStandard {name: "B"})
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree({
  startNode: BaseStandard, 
  endNodes: [CompareStandard], 
  relationshipFilter: "RELATION_TYPE>", 
  labelFilter: "+NeoCRE|NeoStandard",
  maxLevel: 20
}) YIELD path
RETURN path

and extracting subgraphs with
// Extract a subgraph within a limited radius
MATCH (BaseStandard:NeoStandard {name: "A"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(BaseStandard, {
  maxLevel: 10,
  labelFilter: "+NeoCRE|NeoStandard",
  relationshipFilter: "RELATED|CONTAINS|LINKED_TO|SAME|AUTOMATICALLY_LINKED_TO>"
}) YIELD nodes, relationships
WITH nodes, relationships, BaseStandard
UNWIND nodes AS node
MATCH (node)-[rel:%]->(CompareStandard:NeoStandard {name: "B"})
WHERE node:NeoCRE OR node:NeoStandard
RETURN DISTINCT rel


You say you tried apoc.path.spanningTree. Was it not fast enough?

So a couple of options come to my mind. You can always try apoc this way in order to find the shortest path between points (without reusing node along the path):
///I expect them to be unique otherwise an undesired cartisian product will happen here
MATCH (BaseStandard:NeoStandard {name: "A"}), (CompareStandard:NeoStandard {name: "B"})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(BaseStandard, {
  labelFilter: "+NeoCRE|NeoStandard",
  terminatorNodes: [CompareStandard],
  uniqueness : "NODE_PATH",
  optional : true,
  limit : 1
}) YIELD path
RETURN path

Adding a valid relationshipFilter will help improving performance too.
A valid cypher that can be further improve with new QPP aditions in the near future is:
MATCH (BaseStandard:NeoStandard {name: "A"}), (CompareStandard:NeoStandard {name: "B"})
MATCH p = (BaseStandard)--(:NeoCRE)(
    (a)--(b) WHERE (b<>BaseStandard) AND (b:NeoCRE or b=CompareStandard)
)+(CompareStandard)
WITH p, length(p) as hops
RETURN p ORDER by hops desc limit 1

In general, not knowing the nature of your graph, I may worry about handling cycles on your pure cypher implementation.

thanks for the answer! the graph has no cycles, its a simple UAG (undirected acyclical)
